# First list is missing in nested list code

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, while-loop, nested-lists

```
group = 0
position = 0
end = "n"

while (end == "n"):
    group = group + 1
    xy = [[] for xy in range(group)]
    xy[position].append(int(input("Input x value: ")))
    xy[position].append(int(input("Input y value: ")))
    position = position + 1
    end = input("Last entries? [y/n] ")

print (xy)
```

**Output**

```
Input x value: 1
Input y value: 2
Last entries? [y/n] n
Input x value: 3
Input y value: 4
Last entries? [y/n] y
[[], [3, 4]]
```

My first list is missing and I don't understand why. How to solve this?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (*"why isn't this code working?"*) must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thanks for the advice. will take note in future question posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you run this line every loop:

```
xy = [[] for xy in range(group)]
```

This re-assigns `xy` to a list of empty lists.

Consider the following code, which simplifies your existing effort:

```
end = "n"
xy = []

while (end == "n"):
    xy.append([int(input("Input x value: ")), int(input("Input y value: "))])
    end = input("Last entries? [y/n] ")

print (xy)
```

Answer (score 1):

you are redefining the list xy each time, so all lists are deleted, only the last one will be saved.

Here's the code a bit edited for it to works:

```py
end = "n"
xy = []

while (end == "n"):
    a = int(input("Input x value: "))
    b = int(input("Input y value: "))
    xy.append([a,b])
    end = input("Last entries? [y/n] ")

print (xy)
```

With this code, you don't even need to use `group` and `position` variables.

You can simplify it more, but less readable:

```py
end = "n"
xy = []

while (end == "n"):
    xy.append([int(input("Input x value: ")), int(input("Input y value: "))])
    end = input("Last entries? [y/n] ")

print (xy)
```